# Android, Glide Image Loading Library: NullPointerException, ProviderInfo

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-glide

Just getting into the Glide image loading library for Android. Currently working with some code from here:
https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/459

My full project is here is you want to look at it:

https://github.com/mhurwicz/glide02

I'm getting the following exception when I run the app in the emulator in Android Studio:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

This is the key statement in MainActivity:

```
new ShareTask(this).execute("http://thelink");
```

(`thelink` is actually `goo.gl/gEgYUd` -- couldn't leave that in above because stackoverflow doesn't allow URL shorteners. )

Here is my code for the ShareTask class

```
class ShareTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, File> {
    private final Context context;

    public ShareTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override protected File doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url = params[0]; // should be easy to extend to share multiple images at once
        try {
            return Glide
                    .with(context)
                    .load(url)
                    .downloadOnly(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)
                    .get() // needs to be called on background thread
                    ;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.w("SHARE", "Sharing " + url + " failed", ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
    @Override protected void onPostExecute(File result) {
        if (result == null) { return; }
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getPackageName(), result);
        share(uri); // startActivity probably needs UI thread
    }

    private void share(Uri result) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/jpeg");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Shared image");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Look what I found!");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, result);
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share image"));
    }
}
```

Using debug, it seems I may be running into trouble at the `get()` statement. For one thing, the width and the height are very large negative numbers. (See the code highlighted in green below.) Then the `get()` statement returns `null`. (See the code highlighted in red below.)

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

[image]

Comment: please provide more logs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NPE is coming from `FileProvider.getUriForFile` because you're passing in the wrong authority. You declared `android:authorities="com.example.fileprovider"` in the manifest, but you're using the package name at the call. This fails to resolve the `info` in `FileProvider.parsePathStrategy`. Match those two strings up and you'll be good to go.

The easiest fix is to use `android:authorities="${applicationId}"`, this leads to 0 hardcoded strings, so you can keep using `context.getPackageName()`.

Regarding your concerns during debug:

- `Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL` is declared to be `MIN_VALUE`, hence the large number
- it's not returning `null`, IDEA is just confused about where it is in the method, that `return null;` shouldn't be executed if it fails in the `FileProvider` code.
- `doGet(null)`: `null` is the timeout here, it's guarded properly in code

I've run the app and weirdly I got a log line saying

> W/SHARE: Sharing http://... failed

but not a stack trace, which is weird, because `ex` cannot be `null` in a `catch`!

Comment: Thanks, @TWiStErRob - That did clear up that problem.  However, I am now getting IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/.   Details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754799/android-illegalargumentexception-failed-to-find-configured-root-that-contains